# How to change VARCHAR length in PRIMARY KEY in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, primary-key, alter-table, varchar

I need to change the `VARCHAR` length from 20 to 25 in a code column in a library table in SQL Server 2014, but SSMS wants to DROP and RE-CREATE all my tables where the library table in question is linked to.

Is there a way to change the `VARCHAR` length of a PRIMARY KEY without dropping all the tables?

Comment: Are you running into this issue? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956176/error-message-when-you-try-to-save-a-table-in-sql-server-saving-changes-is-not-permitted

Comment: I think you mean foreign keys not PK? Nothing is stopping you from altering VARCHAR columns with an index or PK as long as you stay within the limits.

Answer (score 2):

As you are increasing the length you can just do an alter column, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
    (
      C1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
                     CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY ,
      C2 INT
    );
GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.T1
VALUES  ( 'test', 1 ),
        ( 'test2', 2 );
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.T1 ALTER COLUMN C1 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
```

Further reading on the `ALTER TABLE` syntax at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql

Comment: I don't think this will work as is, if the column in question has foreign keys that reference it.

Comment: This is true, but OP does not mention FK references.

Comment: From the OP: "DROP and RE-CREATE all my tables where the *library table in question is linked to*." (emphasis added).

Comment: I did not extrapolate that as there being a foreign key in place. That's my misunderstanding if that's the case.

Comment: Agreed - I could be wrong, just how I read the question. Couldn't think of another reason for it to be wanting to drop and recreate other tables....

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the `ALTER TABLE` command, as in Nic's answer. However, the problem is that there are foreign keys that reference your table.

To get around this, you'll want to script out the foreign keys, drop them to make the change, and then recreate them after you've updated the tables.

Here's a [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/?utm_source=dailynewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=headline&utm_campaign=20160818) to a script by Aaron Bertrand for scripting out the command to drop and create your foreign keys.

NOTE: I would also update the column in the other tables that use it, to make sure that all allowed values will fit in those other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has not been touched for over 5 years, but RDFozz is correct, the question hasn't been answered.
This is what I did recently:

> Replace {YourTable} and {YourCol} appropriately.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @{YourTable}{YourCol}Len int = (SELECT COL_LENGTH ( 'dbo.{YourTable}' , '{YourCol}' ) )
    ,   @New{YourCol}Len int 

PRINT 'Looking to increase the size of the {YourTable}.{YourCol} column:'
IF @{YourTable}{YourCol}Len { 100
BEGIN
    PRINT ' The field is undersized at '+CAST(@{YourTable}{YourCol}Len AS varchar(100) )+' - increasing it to 100'
    PRINT '     } Drop PK constraint on {YourTable}.{YourCol}'

    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[{YourTable}]') AND type in (N'U'))
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{YourTable}] DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS [PK_{YourTable}] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF );

    PRINT '     } Increase {YourTable}.{YourCol} from 32 to varchar(100)'
    ALTER TABLE dbo.{YourTable} ALTER COLUMN {YourCol} varchar(100) NOT NULL;

    PRINT '     } Add PK constraint on {YourTable}.{YourCol}'
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{YourTable}] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_{YourTable}] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        ( [{YourCol}] ASC )

    SET @New{YourCol}Len = +(SELECT COL_LENGTH ( 'dbo.{YourTable}' , '{YourCol}' ) )
    PRINT '     } {YourTable}.{YourCol} is now '+CAST(@New{YourCol}Len AS varchar(100) )
END
ELSE IF @{YourTable}{YourCol}Len }= 100
BEGIN
    PRINT ' {YourTable}.{YourCol} column is OK - currently '+CAST(@{YourTable}{YourCol}Len AS varchar(100) )
END
ELSE PRINT 'The {YourTable} table does not seem to exist!'

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

> NB: The Primary Key needs dropping and re-creating

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the actual problem in the question, which is the  child tables with dependent foreign key constraints.

Comment: Mmm, I don't think so  The question is, "_Is there a way to **change the VARCHAR length of a PRIMARY KEY** without dropping all the tables?_" Though, you are correct in that if there are any FKs, they will also need to be changed in which case the above could be used but replacing the drop/recreate PK with drop/recreate FK.

Answer (score -6):

Try to uncheck "Deny saving changes which needed recreation of a table".
In SQL Managenet St. click on bar, choise Service - Parameters, select Diesigners - Table and Database Constructors. Then unscheck "Deny saving changes which needed recreation of a table".

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm greatly mistaken, the user isn't looking to have SQL Server drop and recreate the tables; he's trying to avoid this. The change you recommend means that SQL would go ahead and drop and recreate the tables, possibly without adequate warning. You can always get the code SQL would have used to make the change, so you can review it and run it manually, if you like.